# Meaning of "no <things> must/should [...]"

Tags: modal-verbs, negation

I want to write a code comment that means "every line in this file *must be shorter than N*". I wrote this:

> No line in this file shall be longer than N

...then considered using "must", which is more commonly used:

> No line in this file must be longer than N.

Intuitively, for some reason, I read the first as my intended meaning ("lines *must be shorter* than N"), but the second as "lines *do not have to be longer* than N), which is different.

I don't know of any rule that would give these two sentences different meanings, it is just how I intuitively parse it. I guess that I am wrong about at least one of them.

Do these two lines have the same meaning? Do they mean "every line *must be shorter* than N", or "lines *can be shorter* than N"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I considered clarifying, but figured it doesn't matter for my question and would just take space. I would read it as "shorter or equal" since that's how my math teachers talked, but YMMV. :)

Comment: Just realized that you're right, it does actually change the meaning... That wasn't intended, I am asking about the sentence structure and not the N/N-1 problem. I want to know if my sentence constrains all lines, or on the contrary says "the lines do *not* have a minimum length", if that makes sense.

Comment: OK, that was the answer to my badly phrased question, thanks. I wondered if "no line must be longer than N" actually meant "it is not mandatory that lines are longer than N" (i.e "no line is subject to that constraint"), and if that was different depending on the verb (must or shall).

Comment: Ah, so it means "no line has a minimum length of N", right?

Comment: What's wrong with your original sentence? It says what you mean to express quite well. Why change it?

Comment: @JasonBassford Do you mean "every line in this file must be shorter than N"? I wondered if the others were appropriate too, and I didn't want to move on without knowing the answer. :) Michael Harvey's "max line length 80" works too for all I care, I just wanted to learn a bit of grammar.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure why you were trying to rephrase it. *The maximum line length is X* also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'every' or 'no' in these ways to express a limit

Every X must/shall be less than Y.

or

No X shall be greater than Y.

Every suitcase must/shall weigh 15 kilos or less.
No suitcase shall weigh more than 15 kilos.